# How to check if an entity inside completablefuture is null

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I am trying to understand CompletableFurue in Java and I am stuck with the following.

```
CompletableFuture<String> cf = getString();
```

I want to check if the String present inside the completable future is "null" or not. How can I do this without using the get() or join() function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't, because the value may not be available yet.

What you can do, is move the check (and follow-up logic) inside the `CompletableFuture`, using one of its many methods. For instance:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> cf2 = cf.thenAccept(value -> {
    if (value != null) {
        // do something with the value
    }
});
```